# Proving Algebra Relation is Equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$R$ is a sets of positive integers that $((a,b),(c,d))\in R \leftrightarrow a.c=b.d$

Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Your thoughts, please??

Comment: i'm asked to use algebra, so i can't test sample numbers. i'm stuck there. Prove that it's symmetrical, reflective, and transitive.